# How to use PLAN with UPDATE OR INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-execution-plan, insert-update, firebird2.5

I am using *Firebird 2.5* and came across a problem that I can not resolve by myself.

There is a statement using `UPDATE OR INSERT INTO`. I would like to make it use a specific execution plan. But - no matter where I place the `PLAN` - I get following error message (line number varies with `PLAN`'s position):

> Invalid token.
>   Dynamic SQL Error.
>   SQL error code = -104.
>   Token unknown - line 2, column 5.
>   plan.

I did not find anything about the usage of `PLAN` with `UPDATE OR INSERT INTO` in the [corresponding documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html).

Aspects of my question: Is it even possible to use them together? Does this work or is it planned to work in a later version of *Firebird*? Is there an obvious reason it does not work, that I did not see? Which alternatives exist to circumvent this?

Comment: why do you want to "use a specific execution plan"?

Comment: @EstebanP. There is a corresponding index that matches the `matching`-clause of the statement. I want Firebird to use it regardless of the current index selectivity because that may be outdated and I *know* it is the best index for this statement. Additionally I like to have dependencies for indices.

Comment: Actually, I understand, that there might be no *need* to use a `plan`. I just want to know, whether and if not - why it is not possible - to use it in this case.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to explicitly specify plan for multi-statement variative commands (MERGE and UPDATE-OR-INSERT). Those are basically branching meta-instructions, which chose different "execution paths" with regard to some conditions. And there is not "conditional branching" in plan subclauses syntax. Thus, it just is not possible. If you really need it - use Stored Procedure with `For Select ... As Cursor` loop.
You may also ask at https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/mailman/firebird-devel/ or http://sql.ru/forum/interbase

Comment: No mention of PLAN subclause here either http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=update_or_insert

Comment: c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\doc\sql.extensions\README.plan.txt quote: "A PLAN clause may be used in all select expressions, including subqueries, derived tables and view definitions. It can be also used in UPDATE and DELETE statements, because they're implicitly based on select expressions." - as you can see MERGE, EXECUTE BLOCK or U-OR-I are not even mentioned

Comment: @Arioch'The Thank you very much for your explanations. Considering you an absolute Firebird expert, I would appreciate these as an acceptable answer.

Comment: I am not expert, just a user. Maybe KDV or someone from sql.ru would come and hammer the final sentence :-D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148207/discussion-between-rene-hoffmann-and-arioch-the).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in Firebird 2.5 (and also not possible in 3.0). Looking at the [parser definition](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/B2_5_Release/src/dsql/parse.y), the `PLAN` clause is only supported on:

- [select query specification](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/B2_5_Release/src/dsql/parse.y#L3419)
- [searched delete](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/B2_5_Release/src/dsql/parse.y#L3809)
- [searched update](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/B2_5_Release/src/dsql/parse.y#L3827)

For a [`merge`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge) statement it should be possible to specify a plan for the source (if it is a select query), but not for the merge itself. The plan clause is not defined for [`update or insert`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-update-or-insert) (nor is it for `insert`, for example).

As far as I am aware there is nothing planned to add this to Firebird 4. You should consider adding an improvement ticket in the tracker, but I don't know if this is even possible at all.